# Who or what is SUDA in Facebook feeds?

Tags: facebook

This comment appears in some Atom feeds from Facebook:

```
<!-- SUDA was here.  10.36.217.112 -->
```

What does it mean?

Comment: If it's only some feeds, is there anything that the feeds have in common or what's different about these feeds to the ones that don't have this comment?

Comment: I think I'm only looking at feeds of Walls (possibly other Pages). All of them seem to have it. Here's a Lord of the Rings example: http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=103990509637581

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: This is speculation because I can't find a confirmation, but here goes...

Just based on a couple of things, I'd say it's a marker entry that some kind of cataloging process internal to Facebook puts in.

- From Wikipedia:

> The Suda or Souda (Greek: Σοῦδα) is a
>   massive 10th century Byzantine
>   encyclopedia of the ancient
>   Mediterranean world...

- All the sample entries that I can find use an address on the 10.0.0.0 subnet which is a private network.  If it is a marker entry and the IP is the address of the system entering in the marker then it's internal to Facebook as it's a private IP.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few possibilities.

1. SUDA is the name of the server hosting the content
2. It's an Easter Egg left in by a programmer.
3. It's the name of the program that pulls the data.